# Functional Interface giving error in eclipse

Tags: functional-interface

```java
@FunctionalInterface
 interface GetQuery {

    abstract StringBuilder fetchQuery();

}
```

I have written code like above but it says not a functional interface. why is that?

Should the functional interface be always inside a class?

Comment: annotation is in the line above. not in same line

Comment: I compiled your example code and it has no errors, it's fine.